# Recover 12.04.3 LTS - Unable to mount /

Tags: boot, grub2, mount

Message from Ubuntu "The disk drive for / is not ready or not present.

The contents of the disk appear to be OK.  I can mount it to another Ubuntu session and view all of the files accessible to a user.

The initial failure is related to a bad memory upgrade attempt.  The timing was wrong and not allowing the system to boot.  Once the memory issue was corrected, UBUNTU won't boot with the message above.  Using the recovery option eventually brings the same message but on a black screen instead of the usual purple Ubuntu screen.

Is there an installation process that can **repair** the existing installation rather than replacing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you what you are looking for is, "boot-repair"

Boot using a live distro.

Install by running "sudo apt-get install boot-repair" in terminal.

Rest of the process should be clear to you. Its all in GUI.